# Sum function is missing at the bottom right of the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, time, sum, number-formatting, duration

I use google spreadsheet and I need a total of time (in `hh:mm:ss` format) while selecting multiple entries using the sum function. It seems the sum functionality was working earlier and now it got disappeared. Please see the below screenshot.

[image: Google spreadsheet]

How to get it back? Please help me.

**Google has restored this feature.

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Looks like spreadsheets does not support SUM for date or time values in this quick calculations corner. Setting formatting to Duration does not help.

Comment: @kishkin: No, google sheet by default was supporting this feature for sum of the time values. I don't know why this feature was removed and how to get it back?

Comment: Hey guys, it seems Google has restored this feature. I've added a screenshot in my question  :)

Answer (score 0):

could be formatting issue but the formula to sum times into duration would be:

```
=TEXT(SUM(A1:A4); "[h]:mm:ss")
```

Comment: This only allows to compute the sum for a fixed range. The original feature worked for an arbitrary selection.